# appearance of scrollbar is moving the objects in my site

Tags: php, html, css, browser, scrollbar

I have this site, written in php, and when the content is large enough the vertical scrollbar shows up. useful thing, obviously, but I need to find a way so that it doesn't dislocate the site content a little to the left!

also can anyone tell me how can I handle the fact that when I manually change the size of the browser window, all the content compress in order to fit in the window?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> useful thing, obviously, but i need to find a way so that it doesn't dislocate the site content a little to the left!

This can be a very annoying effect when switching between pages that have the same basic layout. The only way I know to prevent it is forcing a vertical scroll bar at all times:

```
body { overflow-y: scroll }
```

I often find it worth doing to ensure a smooth experience.

Internet Explorer reserves space for the scroll bar by default, no matter whether one is needed or not. It's one of the few things it does better than the other browsers.

Comment: sometimes overflow-y is not sufficient. use it in combination with overflow-x: none (or what ever you like). I needed to set both before the vertical scrollbar would show up.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid mmm, I'm not aware of any browser where you need to specify one to get the other, and can't see anything in the [MDC docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Overflow-x) either. Do you remember in which browser/s and/or which circumstance/s this happened to you? I'd be interested in hearing about them.

Comment: Way off topic but I like this idea for scroll bars. http://vimeo.com/20570173 and http://vimeo.com/20523493 I am not so keen on space being reserved.

Comment: It was in mozilla firefox (4). I had to force a vertical scrollbar into a div with was generated with jqeury. I still don't know the exact reason why I had to set both, maybe it was because of the jquery. I'll check it again :).

Comment: @Treffynnon very interesting! And indeed a solution to the problem.

Comment: yeap overflow-y did the trick!!
@Treffynnon very interesting indeed! but what about full-screen applications?

Comment: @Pekka I was half wrong... It didn't show up because of an error in my code. Nonetheless I did needed them both to cover the 'error'. It is hard to reproduce the error... So when your code is without bugs, overflow-y will do the job :).

Comment: @gianniskpf It will overlay the content when the mouse is in context rather than appearing outside the application pane. You can see it in the second video when he demos it being close to the edge of the screen.

Comment: @Treffynnon oops didn't quite notice!

also, any help with the browser window issue? :)

Comment: @giannis re browser window, the non-Javascript way is to use relative dimensions. `width: 100%; height: 100%` will create a rectangle that compresses according to the window's dimensions.

Comment: @pekka sorry i wasn't clear. i don't want that to happen, just the content "covered" by the window as i change its dimensions. i already use relative dimensions though, and when i change the height of the window, everything is ok, this isn't happening when i change the width

Comment: @giannis ah, I see! Mmm, if you don't want to use JS, you will need to set a pixel width in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is that the scroll bar shifts the content?

The easiest way to do this is to ensure that that height is always a little bigger than the window to ensure that the scroll bar is ALWAYS there, so the content is ALWAYS shifted, therefore no shift.

```
body {
 min-height: 101%;
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: The downside of this is that the scroll bar will be active, suggesting there is something for the user to see if they move it. I'd recommend forcing a disabled scroll bar using `overflow-y` instead

Answer (score 0):

I normally prefer the method that Pekka mentions, but

```
body {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

can be used if you need you need valid CSS 2.1 for whatever reason.